# Is it possible to limit the number of results that the embeddable calendar displays?

Tags: embed, google-calendar-api

I have a requirement to let the user define the number of items that are returned by the embeddable calendar display in agenda mode.
I am also wondering if the date that is returned in the date-label area can be modified (formatted differently).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, so don't use it and build your own!